# og:site_name ignored for facebook comments plugin?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'm using Facebook's comment plugin, and I have point to a page with open graph tags set up.

When a user makes a comment on my page using the plugin, all of the og tags are used by facebook in the wall post, except og:site_name, which should go in the caption of the link but instead the domain of my site is appearing.

example HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site Name" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/some_image.png" />
<meta property="og:description" content="This is a description" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="FB_APP_ID" />
</head>
<body>
.....
</body>
</html>
```

But here's what I end up seeing on Facebook:

[example](http://www.enr-corp.com/PhotoDir/example.png)

Note the caption says "www.example.com" instead of "My Site Name" which I expected to see there.

Anyone know why OG would be ignoring my tag?

Thanks in advance,

DW

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix but a possible reason.

There's an opened issue in the Facebook Bug DB:
[Incorrect site name appearing in shared links on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/300209246794269/)

Unfortunately, it seems to be a low priority issue.